# Inconsistency between `MkNthFieldLens` and `>>(n: Nat)` in Shapeless 2.1

Tags: scala, shapeless

Suppose, I want to modify the first element of a tuple using shapeless lenses.

With witness:

```
import shapeless._
def modifyKey[A,B](t: (A, B))(f: A => A)(implicit mk: MkNthFieldLens[(A,B), _1]) = 
  (lens[(A, B)] >> '_1).modify(t)(f)
```

With Nat:

```
import nat._
def modifyKey[A,B](t: (A, B))(f: A => A) = (lens[(A, B)] >> _0).modify(t)(f)
```

So I have to use `>> _0` instead of `>> _1` here, otherwise it's trying to take `B`:

```
scala> def modifyKey[A,B](t: (A, B))(f: A => A) = (lens[(A, B)] >> _1).modify(t)(f)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A => A
 required: B => B
       def modifyKey[A,B](t: (A, B))(f: A => A) = (lens[(A, B)] >> _1).modify(t)(f)
                                                                                 ^
```

Is such "0 vs 1" numeration is intentional, or am I having some trouble with my Shapeless (I use 2.1 version with scala 2.11.5)?